Revit API Find location of collaboration cache in 2024
As of Revit 2024, the end user can change the location of their collaboration cache through the UI.  Is this location available in the API?  If so where can it be found?  I thought I had found it before but I don't see it now.

I have asked the development team for you.

Any update from development?

Not yet, re-prompted and still waiting...

The collaboration cache location is stored in the Revit.ini file:
[CloudModelCache]
CacheLocation=C:\Users\hume\AppData\Local\Autodesk\Revit\Autodesk Revit 2026

It takes effect in the next Revit session after update, so it may not be a good idea to expose it via the Revit API. The workaround is to overwrite the contents in Revit.ini. For read access, this solution is perfect.
